# Update shared element before reentering first activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, shared-element-transition

I have a shared element between two activities, It works fine, `Activity` A is  master (containing a `RecyclerView`) and `Activity` B is detail one. Sometimes I need to change data in detail mode and I want to apply this changes to `Activity` A before **Reenter Transition** but after change and notifying the `Adapter` when I press back app crashes, I use `LocalBroadcastManager` to reflect changes, This is the crash log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ViewGroup.transformMatrixToGlobal(android.graphics.Matrix)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at android.view.GhostView.calculateMatrix(GhostView.java:95)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityTransitionCoordinator$GhostViewListeners.onPreDraw(ActivityTransitionCoordinator.java:951)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2435)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1343)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6853)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:825)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:619)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:579)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:811)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6102)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

**Activity A (where I update my UI)**:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int index = intent.getIntExtra(Constants.EXTRA_ORDER_INDEX, -1);
            if (index != -1) {
                Order order = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.EXTRA_ORDER);
                if (order != null) {
                    OrderItem orderItem =
                            (OrderItem) mItemsAdapter.getAdapterItems().get(index);
                    orderItem.setOrder(order);
                    mItemsAdapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
                }
            }
        }
```

**What I tried and didn't work:**
1. I updated `id` and `transitionName` on the changed child view in `RecyclerView`
2. Notified my adapter in `onResume` but changes was applied after transition.
3. invoked `setLayoutFrozen` and the same result as #2

**Note:**  I need to apply changes before reenter transition, I **DO NOT** want to update UI after transition.
Is this the right approach ? Any idea what I'm missing ?
If you need more details to help me out please let me know, Thanks